# Beautiful soup - getText from multiple pages

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape the following page:
http://www.interzum.com/exhibitors-and-products/exhibitor-index/exhibitor-index-15.php

I want to loop through each of the exhibitor links, and get the contact details. I then need to do this across all of the 77 pages.

I can pull the information I need from a page, but when it gets to building functions and looping and I keep getting errors and can't find a simple structure for looping through multiple pages.

This is what I have so far in a jupyter notebook:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import time
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.interzum.com/exhibitors-and-products/exhibitor-index/exhibitor-index-15.php'
text = requests.get(url).text
page1 = BeautifulSoup(text, "html.parser")

def get_data(url):
    text = requests.get(url).text
    page2 = BeautifulSoup(text, "html.parser")

    title = page2.find('h1', attrs={'class':'hl_2'}).getText()    
    content = page2.find('div', attrs={'class':'content'}).getText()
    phone = page2.find('div', attrs={'class':'sico ico_phone'}).getText()
    email = page2.find('a', attrs={'class':'sico ico_email'}).getText
    webpage = page2.find('a', attrs={'class':'sico ico_link'}).getText


    data = {'Name': [title],
          'Address': [content],
          'Phone number': [phone],
          'Email': [email],
          'Web': [web]            
         } 

df = pd.DataFrame()
for a in page1.findAll('a', attrs={'class':'initial_noline'}):
    df2 = get_data(a['href'])
    df = pd.concat([df, df2])



AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'getText'
```

I know the errors I keep getting are because I am struggling with the syntax of functions and looping.

What is the recommended structure for this?

Comment: Please share the full error message.

Comment: Your function isn't returning anything. You should end it with something like `return data`

Comment: couple errors in the code: you are looking for 'a' for email and webpage, those are in divs. You have web in one place, and webpage in another place. The URL is not the full URL, you need to add your domain like `get_data('http://www.interzum.com' + a['href'])`. Finally, not all links are valid links. The ones you need have kid=some id in them. To filter for those links only, use `if 'kid=' not in a['href'] : continue`. Before putting your function in a `def` make sure it works with a single sample, and then use it as a function.

Answer (score 0):

Your code alternately calls a function getText (.getText()) and accesses an attribute getText (.getText) on a return value that may be none.

```
python
>>> a = None
>>> type(a)
<type 'NoneType'>
>>> a.foo()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'foo'
>>> a.foo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'foo'
>>>
```

Review the BeautifulSoup docs, and determine what `.find()` returns and how to properly access the parsed data within.

Answer (score 0):

Here is somewhat debugged version.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.interzum.com/exhibitors-and-products/exhibitor-index/exhibitor-index-15.php'
text = requests.get(url).text
page1 = BeautifulSoup(text, "html.parser")

def get_data(url):
    text = requests.get(url).text
    page2 = BeautifulSoup(text, "html.parser")

    title = page2.find('h1', attrs={'class':'hl_2'}).getText()    
    content = page2.find('div', attrs={'class':'content'}).getText()
    phone = page2.find('div', attrs={'class':'sico ico_phone'}).getText()
    email = page2.find('div', attrs={'class':'sico ico_email'}).getText
    webpage = page2.find('div', attrs={'class':'sico ico_link'}).getText


    data = [[title, content,phone, email, webpage]] 
    return data

df = pd.DataFrame()
for a in page1.findAll('a', attrs={'class':'initial_noline'}):
    if 'kid=' not in a['href'] : continue
    print('http://www.interzum.com' + a['href'])
    data = get_data('http://www.interzum.com' + a['href'])
    df.append(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to almost get everything I need. My code is the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import time

binary = FirefoxBinary('geckodriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://www.interzum.com/exhibitors-and-products/exhibitor-        index/exhibitor-index-15.php')

url = 'http://www.interzum.com/exhibitors-and-products/exhibitor-index/exhibitor-index-15.php'
text = requests.get(url).text
page1 = BeautifulSoup(text, "html.parser")

def get_data(url, tries=0, max_tries=3):
    text_test2 = requests.get(url).text
    page2 = BeautifulSoup(text_test2, "html.parser")

    try:
        title = page2.find('h1', attrs={'class':'hl_2'}).text    
        content = page2.find('div', attrs={'class':'cont'}).text
        phone = page2.find('div', attrs={'class':'sico ico_phone'}).text
        email_div = page2.find('div', attrs={'class':'sico ico_email'})
        email = email_div.find('a', attrs={'class': 'xsecondarylink'})['href']
    
    
       if page2.find_all("div", {"class": "sico ico_link"}):
            web_div = page2.find('div', attrs={'class':'sico ico_link'})
            web = web_div.find('a', attrs={'class':'xsecondarylink'})['href']

    except:
        if tries < max_tries:
            tries += 1
            print("try {}".format(tries))
            return get_data(url, tries)
    

    data = {'Name': [title],
            'Street address': [content], 
            'Phone number': [phone],
            'Email': [email],
            'Web': [web]            
            }
    
    return pd.DataFrame(data=data)


df = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(0,80):
    print(i)
    page1 = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')


    for div in page1.findAll('div', attrs={'class':'item'}):

        for a in div.findAll('a', attrs={'class':'initial_noline'}):
            if 'kid=' not in a['href'] : continue
            print('http://www.interzum.com' + a['href'])

            data = get_data('http://www.interzum.com' + a['href'])
            df = pd.concat([df, data])
        
    next_button = driver.find_element_by_class_name('slick-next')
    next_button.click()
    time.sleep(20)

df.to_csv('result.csv')
```

This code is working until it gets to the second link on the second page.